# Convert .mp4 to .ogg keeping only the audio, with Ubuntu 14.04 and avconv

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, conversion, avconv, video-conversion

How to convert a .mp4 file (downloaded from YouTube) to .ogg? (keeping only the audio)

When Ubuntu had ffmpeg I could just do `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -acodec vorbis file.ogg`

Now we have to do without ffmpeg, but avconv seems to have a different syntax:

```
$ avconv -i file.mp4 -nv file.ogg
Unrecognized option 'nv'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: Have you tried using the same syntax as ffmpeg?

Comment: @saiarcot895: Yes, it results in an empty file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Nicolas Raoul you made a little mistake, it's not `-nv` it's `-vn` try:

```
avconv -i file.mp4 -vn file.ogg
```

it will work.

Comment: In the event that subtitle stream would be present in the file (i'm unsure if MP4 have them), you can also specify `-sn` to be safe.

Comment: How about compression? My downloaded mp4 file 6.5 mb and converted oog file is 33.5 mb. There is a huge difference. How can reduce converted file size?

Comment: @tersakyan: Interesting, but please ask this as a new question :-)

Comment: Unfortunately and disappointedly your answer isn't working for me, it gives `Output file #0 does not contain any stream` in the console/terminal.

Comment: did you try it on other files?

Comment: `Output file #0 does not contain any stream` is what I get when I forget the `-i`